# Wrong loop count of Immutable.js sequence in React

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

In a component of my React app I have the following code:

```
render() {
  console.log("render");
  const x = Immutable.Map({a: 1, b: 2});

  return (
    <div>
      {x.entrySeq().map(() => {
        console.log("here");
        return (<div></div>)
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The strange thing is that the loop inside the `map` function is executed 6 times (I get one `render` on the console, but 6 times `here`). I would have expected just 2 times the `here` in the console. Why is it called 6 times? Maybe sequences in Immutable.js do work differently than I expect.

#### Update:

I created a very simplistic App using `create-react-app` to demonstrates that problem that can [be found on Github](https://github.com/medihack/test-immutable-react) (clone -> `npm run start` -> browse to localhost:3000 -> watch console). Strangely I couldn't reproduce the problem on a Codepen.

Comment: Perhaps there is a issue using `map` with `Seq`, the problem is not present when you try `x.entrySeq().toArray()` or even `x.entrySeq.forEach()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because [`Seq`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Seq) is lazy.
This means that **the function you pass to `.map()` isn't called until the `Seq` is iterated**.

Here's what I think happens. When you call

```
x.entrySeq.map(...)
```

this creates a new `Seq`.
Your render function then returns this `Seq` back to react.
At this point, `console.log("here")` still hasn't been called.

Now react is storing this `Seq` in its component tree.
Every time react traverses this part of the tree (which doesn't only happen while rendering) it will iterate through your `Seq`, which in turn will call the function you passed to `.map()`.

If you want to avoid this recomputation every time react decides to traverse this part of the tree, you need to cache the output of your `Seq`. The easiest way to do this is to tack on `.toArray()` after your `.map(...)`. In this the `Seq` will be iterated through once immediately, then stored in an array which you then give to react.